# How to make a simlpe minimal webtemplate vs sln 

Tags: site-definition

I would like to create a simple web template that is based on a blank site definition, with only the wiki home page feature enabled.

I would like to do this by "save as template" in SD, and importing the project in visual studio.

Question is: When, in the import project in vs, select to import only the webtemplate, it seems to be dependet on everything else, so that my generated sln contains a lot of fields, contenttypes and modules. When all I was hoping for was a nice clean webtemplate to start from. How can I create a simple vs sln that contains a minimal webtemplate?

Regards

larsi

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, with SharePoint Development, when we want something cleaner, we end up doing manual work :)

I would start with VS.NET solution and start with "Site Definition". once you are done, VS.NET would start with mimimal onet.xml. Then point ownwards, you can start copying the things you need from out of the box onet.xml files located on SharePoint root.